# localStorage code working perfectly in Opera, but only half in Safari

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, local-storage, opera

I have been coding my PWA for about a week now and I need some help finding out why the code works completely in Opera, but not in Safari.

How to replicate my issue:

1. Open my project ([link](https://github.com/rohilpatel1/Calebra)) in both Safari (on mac or iphone or whatever) and Opera (or chrome or whatever)
2. Click the 3rd button from the left and make a meal (make some random stuff up)
3. Once you have made the meal, then notice the toggle switch and switch it on.
4. Reload the page and see that the meal still shows but the toggle doesn't show for safari.
5. It doesn't work in Safari for some reason

Am I using code that shouldn't be allowed in Safari or something? How do I work around this?

## I have deployed a link as well to the site via firebase [here](https://calebra-aa6fa.web.app)

Comment: no one is going to search for code.

Comment: working "only half" isn't a problem statement ... what doesn't work? describe it and add the appropriate code tot he question ... debugging details help too - like developer tools console output for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some debugging on discord, we found that in `script.js`, these lines were causing the issue:

```js
if (mealTargetted) {
      userData.mealInformation.find(a => a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText).addedToShoppingList = false;
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(userData));
} else {
      userData.mealInformation.find(a => a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText).addedToShoppingList = true;
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(userData));
}
```

[Github](https://github.com/rohilpatel1/Calebra/blob/78b13a86859c90d1897a6d9865e37124db636d58/script.js#L77)

## Error

What was happening was that somehow, in safari, `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText` had a trailing space compared to the saved localStorage result:
[image: As you can see, e.innerText has a trailing space]

> `console.log(userData.mealInformation, e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText)`

This meant that `a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText.trim()` was  never satisfied, and so `userData.mealInformation.find(a => a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText)` returns undefined, throwing an `undefined is not an object` error, causing the toggle to appear not to change.

## Solution

What this means was that we had to trim `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText`:

```js
if (mealTargetted) {
      userData.mealInformation.find(a => a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText.trim()).addedToShoppingList = false;
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(userData));
} else {
      userData.mealInformation.find(a => a.name == e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerText.trim()).addedToShoppingList = true;
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(userData));
}
```

So this wasn't a localStorage issue, just a code issue